# How does firebase charge for the method listCollections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make use of the following method `listCollections` which is referenced [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) in the Firestore documentation.

It's unclear to me how this method is charged. I understand we pay for reads and writes, but as this isn't data stored in a document I'm unclear on how this is charged for.

How does Firebase charge for this method?

I've explored the pricing here. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the official documentation, the `listCollections()` function lists all subcollections of a document reference. So this method returns a Promise that contains an array of collection references. This means you read only the name of the sub-collection and not the actual documents within them. In Firestore, you have to pay a read operation for each document you read, no matter if you're using a collection reference or a query. Since the `listCollections()` function returns only references and not documents, then there is nothing that you have to pay. That's also the reason why you didn't find anything in the pricing section.